# backbone.js: What should be a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on an app that has 1 main list of videos, and a playlist that you can add videos to from the main list (http://gosukpop.com).

I'm in the process of "transferring" my project over to backbone.js. I only have views for the main video list table and the playlist table. And I just noticed that you can only capture events that are within the el element(Right?). So I would have to create a view for every thing on the page...like the search, sort options, and playlist controls; is this correct? Or should I just have 2 views for the main list (includes search, sort options) and the playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great thing about Backbone is the flexibility it provides. It doesn't require everything on the page to be Backbonified.

In your case, I would recommend a Backbone view for the main list and one for the play list. (You might also consider an item view for each row in the table in these lists)

The search, sort and playlist controls do not have to be contained within a view.

Just subscribe to their respective events and update the Backbone collections and models as needed.

If you need some help starting out, feel free to send an email to the [Backbone mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/backbonejs). There's a lot of people willing to help out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the mailing list!